# Convert $3^n$ to some form of $2^n$

Tags: exponentiation

I am not from Maths field, but I need your help to convert the $3^n$ form to $2^n$. I need to change the base from $3$ to $2$. The resultant expression can be of any form.

Comment: $2^n=e^{nln(2)}=e^{nln(2)/ln(3)ln(3)}=3^{nln(2)/ln(3)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3 = 2^{\log_23}$$

Therefore $$3^n = (2^{\log_23})^n=2^{n\log_23}$$